# Sequential comparison of 3 variable in if condition giving wrong output in PHP

Tags: php, comparison

I am just curious about sequential value comparison of  three variables value

```
$a=5; $b=6;  $c=7;
```

I have above 3 variables, but tested with different scenarios in below way

```
echo ($c > ($b > $a)) ? "true" : "false";  // output: false;
echo (($c > $b) > $a) ? "true" : "false";  // output: false;

echo intval($b > $a); // output: 1
echo intval($c > $b); // output: 1
```

In above cases $a,$b and $c contains positive numeric value,  if we compare true and `$a` and `$c`  with true by greater/less sign it returns always false

```
echo ($c > true) ? "true": "false"; // output: false
echo (true  > $c) ? "true": "false"; // output: false
echo ($a > true) ? "true": "false"; // output: false
echo (true  > $a ) ? "true": "false"; // output: false
```

**Why comparison gives wrong output with left and right precision** ?? for below conditions

```
echo ($c > ($b > $a)) ? "true" : "false";  // output: false;
echo (($c > $b) > $a) ? "true" : "false";  // output: false;
```

**If compression positive number and Boolean value returns false then  why below comparisions returns false?**

```
echo ($c > true) ? "true": "false"; // output: false
echo (true  > $c) ? "true": "false"; // output: false
```

Comment: @deceze, please chech my modified question for comparision with number and Boolean return false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a boolean is involved in a comparison, [both operands are converted to a boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types). In your case, that means you're always comparing `true > true`, which is clearly `false`.

All your numeric comparisons are `true`, e.g.:

```
$c > ($b > $a)
```

is:

```
→ 7 > (6 > 5)
→ 7 > true
→ true > true
→ false
```

A case which will actually result in `true` is:

```
true > (5 > 6)
→ true > false
→ true
```